# C sort integer numbers from text file with selection sort and write sorted numbers to new file

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a txt file which have unsorted numbers. I want to sort numbers and write them to new text file.
Example input text file is:

> 12 56 34 2 6

I want to sort them and write to output.txt as below:

> 2 6 12 34 56

My code is like this, and like I said, it works when the sorting array of numbers is inside the code but in files it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
void selectionSort(int *arr, int n)
{
    int i, j, min_idx;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
                min_idx = j;

        swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{

    int i = 0, j, n = 0, min, index;

    // declaring array to store data from file
    int arr[100000];

    // declaring file pointer
    FILE *fptr;

    // opening the integer file.
    fptr = fopen("random.txt", "r");

    // scanning integer from file to array
    while (fscanf(fptr, "%d", &arr[i]) == 1)
    {

        // for counting the number of elements
        n++;

        // for incrementing the array index
        i++;
    }

    selectionSort(fptr, n);
 

    // printing the sorted array...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

But I cannot sort numbers. Can you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: why are you passing fptr to selectionSort?

Comment: in order to read the input file. Is it wrong?

Comment: Is `fptr` an `int *`? Enable more compiler warnings.

Comment: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘selectionSort’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     selectionSort(fptr, n);
                   ^~~~
 note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘FILE *’ {aka ‘struct _IO_FILE *’}
 void selectionSort(int *arr, int n)

Comment: Then what is the purpose of arr?

Comment: the purpose of arr after reading input file I want to store them as arr. I am a bit complex

Comment: The function `selectionsort` itself is not supposed to read from the file. That function requires you to pass a pointer of type `int *` to the first element of the array to sort. However, you are passing a `FILE *` instead, which is wrong.

Comment: How can I pass a pointer to first element of a FILE? Thanks

Comment: You have no code in selectionSort to read or write ints in a file. Files can't  be acted upon like arrays. Ints in the file are strings of chars. How would you swap two ints of different lengths for example?

Comment: I solve the problems thanks a lot.                                                                                     
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fptr, "%d", &arr[i]);
    }

Comment: @cereyanci23: You cannot pass "a pointer to the first element of a `FILE`", as a `FILE` is an opaque data structure. Howevever, that is also not what you want to do. In your previous comment, you are asking about an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should pass `arr` instead of `fptr` to the function `selectionSort`.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I copy file content into array and gives pointer to an array into selectionsort function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pass the array `arr` to `selectionSort()` not the file pointer `fptr`.
2. Check return value from `fopen()`.
3. Eliminated the unused time.h header.
4. Eliminated unused variables and minimized scope of the rest (in `main()`).  The old style of declaring variables separately makes it harder to reason about code due to their large scope.
5. Replaced magic value with a symbolic constant and used that to do a boundary check to avoid buffer overflows of `arr`.
6. (Not fixed) Consider using unsigned types for length and swapping the order of the two arguments to `void selectionSort(size_t n, int arr[n])` so you can document how the two are related.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_LEN 100000

void swap(int *xp, int *yp) {
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void selectionSort(int *arr, int n) {
    int i, j, min_idx;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
                min_idx = j;
        swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[ARRAY_LEN];
    FILE *fptr = fopen("random.txt", "r");
    if(!fptr) {
        printf("fopen failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int n = 0;
    for(; fscanf(fptr, "%d", &arr[n]) == 1 && n < ARRAY_LEN; n++);
    selectionSort(arr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
```